# WindowsAzure.Storage on not working on .Net Core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, .net-core

Experimenting with the new .Net Core 1.0 that was released yesterday.
I'm not able to get WindowsAzure.Storage library to work.
The compiler complains about multiple dependencies that don't support `.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0`.

> The dependency Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.4 does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.
>
> The dependency Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4 does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.
>
> The dependency Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4 does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.
>
> The dependency System.Spatial 5.6.4 does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.

Does this mean that the WindowsAzure.Storage SDK isn't ready for .Net Core 1.0 yet?

Comment: Did you select `Include Prelease` when you added the dependency??

Comment: `"WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.0.2-preview"` is the line in project.json

Comment: As of this writing, use [WindowsAzure.Storage 7.1.3-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/7.1.3-preview)

Answer (score 11):

WindowsAzure.Storage [supports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/8.1.1) .NET Standard, but its dependencies do not. Microsoft.Data.OData and System.Spatial do not yet support .NET Standard.

The [library source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/AspNet/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage/project.json#L12) suggests adding the following `imports` property to your `frameworks` section in project.json:

```
"imports": [
    "dnxcore50",
    "portable-net451+win8"
]
```

This will temporarily import the PCL profile that these packages should have existing support for.

In newer csproj-based projects, the `PackageTargetFallback` property accomplishes the same thing:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageTargetFallback>dnxcore50;portable-net451+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This fixes the error for me - but seems to lead to a host of others: "cannot find runtime target for framework", "you may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported", ...

Comment: I needed to also add "type": "platform" as [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2760)